# How to execute T4 template files in Visual Studio For Mac?

Tags: macos, t4, visual-studio-mac

I am unable to run text templates in Visual Studio for Mac or visual studio code.  I tried:

VS > Right click project > Tools > Process T4 templates > (No Templates Found)

I also went to Visual Studio top menu > Extensions > (Search for T4) > IDE Extensions > Text Templating v8.10.6 is installed.

I am trying to use the *.tt template from [linq2db.SqlServer.](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/T4.html).  But running any basic T4 template would let me know the TextTemplatingFileGenerator is at least working.  There the documentation states:

`Make sure that custom tool for your tt file set to TextTemplatingFileGenerator, otherwise it will not run`

Though it doesn't explain how to actually accomplish this task?

I also installed [TT-Processor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aisoftware.tt-processor) into visual studio code.  I was also unable to execute the *.tt file.  In this case I did not see an execute/run command when I right clicked a *.tt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft answered the question for me. As I already mentioned, the part that nobody talks about is the answer to this:

```
Make sure that custom tool for your tt file set to TextTemplatingFileGenerator, otherwise it will not run
```

In visual studio right click the *.tt File > Properties > Custom Tool > Choose "TextTemplatingFileGenereator"

Now visual studio will find the *.tt file when you Right click the project > Tools > Process T4 templates

Arguably, this experience should be improved to default to this behavior to fit the philosophy of "fall into the pit of success".

Comment: thanks for the answer, not sure why the question was marked down - but it helped so thanks for asking and asnwering!

Comment: I can't find this setting in VS2022 for Mac, the list of properties is empty when I select the *.tt file

Comment: @ChristophS. Make sure the file "Build Action" is set to none.