# Code Generation and T4 Text Templates for Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

Upon reading the Microsoft docs, generating or compiling T4 file is not supported in Visual studio for Mac, but does anyone knows any work around for this so that I can compile it in Mac, I always get Could not resolve assembly reference System.Text.Json.

[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to install the package `System.Text.Json` with the nuget package manager?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, yes I already installed the System.Text.Json, still not working.

Comment: Did you download the newest version 6.0.5?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, yes installed the latest.

Comment: Can you show the detail error message or provide a small sample which can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, I included the images to my original post. That's the only thing that I'm doing, process the .tt file and the error shows. But in Windows OS, it's working properly.

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68383285/how-to-execute-t4-template-files-in-visual-studio-for-mac) which processes the .tt file in the vs for mac successfully.